# VBA exit before end

Tags: vba, excel

The code: a commandutton code with two parts, The first part of it sort the cells, and second part is recoloring the sorted cells.

The problem: the macro exit after the first, without doing the recoloring. If I commented the first part, the code does the recoloring.

Any idea, what could be the problem?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim WName As String


''First Part
WName = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
Range("B2:B21").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WName).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WName).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B21"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WName).Sort
    .SetRange Range("B2:B21")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


''Second Part
For i = 2 To 21
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 2).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        Cells(i, 2).Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and it does not exit after first for me. Suggest you step through your code line by line using F8 and see on which line does it break, then post that information if you need more help.

Comment: After the following:

`.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With`

Its just exiting no error msg or anything.

Comment: I've tried it too and no issue as well. Is there something specific in the data that it doesn't like to sort? Have you tried stepping through it on a blank workbook to ensure it's not something wrong with your install?